# Minimal CSS (or JS) solution for a sticky horizontally scrollable tableheader

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html-table

Is it possible to implement the following layout with css only? Given that I use react it doesn't matter if I need to use JS. I'm just curious if it's possible without.

[image: screencap]

If not, what's a simple approach to make a table horizontally scrollable like that?

The columns need to have a variable width.

Comment: Yeah, it's likely possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [table with sticky header and horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70770027/table-with-sticky-header-and-horizontal-scroll)

Comment: @HereticMonkey If you want to close this question, I can add an answer to the linked question. There's some info missing, e.g. that overflow causes sticky to break, also you can't have a fixed header that scrolls with the content because it's removed from the flow. 

It's essentially the same question. I might add a solution for react using hooks if I find some time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You would need to add something like this in your css.

```
.fixed-toolbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: */ (your desired pixel height) */;
}
```

Then make sure your toolbar element has the class `"fixed-toolbar"` as an attribute in your html/jsx.

For the horizontal scroll you could have a series of divs that represent each item. Inside each div you could have 2 elements - one to represent the item name, and the second to represent all the attributes of each item. Make the item name a fixed width and make the second item have a dynamic width but with `overflow: scroll` on it.